# show that $f(x) = x\cdot(x-a)$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $f: \mathbb{R^3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = x\cdot(x-a)$ where $\cdot$ is the dot product. I want to show that $f$ is convex directly from  the definition of convex functions, that is $\forall x, y \in \mathbb{R^3}, \theta \in [0, 1], f(\theta x+(1 - \theta)y) \leq \theta f(x) + (1 - \theta) f(y).$ After I plug in the function in to the definition of convexity and simplifying, I get $(\theta x + (1 - \theta) y) \cdot (\theta x + (1 - \theta) y) \leq \theta x\cdot x + (1 - \theta)y \cdot y$, and I can't get any further. How can we conclude this expression is true? Or I did something wrong during the simplification?

Comment: Hint: First show that $x.x=\|x\|^{2}$ is convex.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy How does this help to show $x \cdot (x - a)$ is convex?

Comment: Hint 2:   $x\cdot(x-a)  = \| x \|^2 - a.x $  :)

Comment: $x.(x-a)=x.x-x.a$

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Keep in mind that I am asking this question out of ignorance.  I was under the impression that if $f(x)$ is any function where $f''(x)$ is defined and always positive on an interval $(a,b)$, then $f(x)$ is convex (i.e. curving upwards) on that interval.  Is this correct?  If so, then isn't the resolution to the problem simply that if $f(x) = x(x-a)$ then $f''(x) = 2$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy It just occurred to me that I am confusing $x \times (x-a)$ with $x \cdot (x-a)$.  If this confusion is the only stumbling block, re the previous comment, can the analysis in the previous comment be *somehow used* to apply to $f(x) = x \cdot (x-a)$?

Answer (score 1):

You almost got there.
$(\theta x+(1-\theta )y)\cdot (\theta x+(1-\theta )y)=\theta^2||x||^2+2\theta(1-\theta)||x||\cdot ||y||+(1-\theta)^2||y||^2 $. Now since $2||x||\cdot ||y||\le ||x||^2+||y||^2$, your result is right there.